# iPhone. MGTwitterEngine. Get info for several users per 1 request

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine, twitter-oauth

Tell me please, how to use getBulkUserInformationFor: method correctly?

I have "Could not authenticate you error". When I use other methods (getUserTimelineFor: for example) all's ok.

At the begining I setup consumer key and consumer secret. And all is works. But when I setup OAuth token with key and secret - it's throw SIGABRT error.

Tell me please, how to get info for several users per 1 request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error was in `OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider` class. I updated it and all it's dependencies to the latest version and now all's ok.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, but I found you need to pass in a NSString of userID's separated by a comma (,) as per this page:

http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/lookup

I.e. 783214,6253282

For example you would use:

[self.twitterEngine getBulkUserInformationFor:@"783214,6253282"];

(remember it's a max of 100 id's at once)

Comment: Yeah, I know it. But getBulkUserInformationFor: method requires OAuth authentification. And problem was in it.